# SSIS Excel File issue - Failure creating file

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssis, etl, ssis-2012

I have SSIS package that grabs excel file and load it to sql table .i get the following error when i run it. I have tried to make run on 64 bit to false. That did not work

i also have installed 64 bit access driver engin . That did not help either.

> Error at Data Flow Task [Excel Source [2]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel Connection Manager" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
>
> Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: Excel Source failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.
>
> Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed validation.
>
> Error at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.
>
> Error at ABC [Connection manager "Excel Connection Manager"]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
>   An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft Access Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Failure creating file.".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Failure creating file

This error is thrown when the Excel connection manager cannot access to the chosen path, it might be caused by:

- You are using a network path / try replacing with a local path
- it might be pointed to your local server, but when it is deployed to another server it will throw error
- you do not have permission to access the selected path from the account that is running the SSIS
- path does not exists

Comment: Nice answer Hadi, i have one concern . If the ssis run locally , my intention is to deploy it on server and call it using stored procedure .

Comment: You can add a variable, use expressions tin excel connectiin manager to read the path from it. And when calling package from stored procedure pass the filename as a parameter (assign a value to the variable)

Comment: i have been adding file name and folder name as excel file path

Comment: @MJ8 are you having permissions to the located path, what is the user that you logged in to sql with it, did he has the permissions needed?

Comment: @MJ8 i don't think there is another issue that may cause this problem other that the 4 issues listed above

Comment: @MJ8 if you need more help. Post the code you are using to call the procedure. And a snapshot of the package

Comment: @MJ8 still waiting for a reply

Comment: @MJ8 why not accepting or upvoting the answer if it solved the issue, else write your own answer

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, to fix it I specified the IP of the shared folder instead of FQDN.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error too, my files are save in a folder OneDrive.
I fix the error by moving the files out from Onerive